# Are the only remaining polio cases in Africa vaccine-derived?

Tags: vaccines, epidemiology, africa

[World Polio Day: Wild poliovirus type 3 declared eradicated](http://www.cidrap.umn.edu/news-perspective/2019/10/world-polio-day-wild-poliovirus-type-3-declared-eradicated):

> Salisbury also said no WPV1 has been detected anywhere on the African continent since 2016. Several African nations, however, are still reporting cases of circulating vaccine-derived polioviruses

Comment: Sad to see that my comment here was deleted.  If folks want to understand this topic they'll need to do some independent investigation, since my knowledge, as a polio survivor, has been rejected.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Your unreferenced-pseudo-answers-in-comments continue to be rejected. Please use the answer box, with links to empirical data, in accordance with the standards of the site.

Comment: @Oddthinking - What I posted wasn't an answer and wasn't intended to be.  It was context, to allow the question to be understood.  Had I posted it as an "answer", with references, I suspect that TPTB here would still have deleted it, as "not an answer".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are most cases of polio derived from the polio vaccine?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42804/are-most-cases-of-polio-derived-from-the-polio-vaccine)

Comment: Something to keep in mind--in the end stage of any battle to eradicate a disease there will be a point where the vaccines cause more harm than the disease.  This is not a reason to stop the fight, failing to fight it means it comes back, but taking the battle to the end means you eliminate all harm from both the disease and the vaccine.